# OpenCV: VideoCapture Stalls on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, opencv, webcam

I'm trying to use `cv.VideoCapture(id)` within Python 3.8 and OpenCV 4.6.0 on Windows 11 to capture the input from a usb camera (c920).
This is on a laptop with a built-in webcam which works fine with `cv.VideoCapture(0)`. I've also verified that VLC can use the usb webcam and that Device Manager "sees" the usb webcam.

However, I've been unable to find an id between -1 and 500 that works for the usb camera.
I notice that initialization does print for id=1, but nothing shows up and the software appears to hang indefinitely.

Is there a way to get this to work with the usb webcam?

Comment: try CAP_DSHOW as an alternative to CAP_MSMF

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, that doesn't work either. CAP_DSHOW seems to cut short the hanging behavior but ultimately the capture fails.

Comment: is there _anything_ going on that might interfere? anything you haven't disclosed so far? anything you think shouldn't matter but still might? do you attempt to open the camera from multiple programs?